# troubles with a fresh install of Xubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo X240

Tags: grub2, xubuntu

I just did a fresh install of Xubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo X240. I got several problems just for doing that :

first one, I was unable to boot without nomodeset checked.

second one, I try first to just install xubuntu, for whatever reason grub intended to be installed on /dev/mmcblk0 but it failed, I was unable to close the popup warning me that grub failed... I was able to select another device/partition where to install grub, but I was not able to click on continue/proceed (I don't remember the word on the button)

then I booted xubuntu and try an installation trough the live usb. Same problem than above... I rebooted and then this time I specified, during the partitionning, where grub should be installed.

at least this time xubuntu was installed!

during the use of the live usb, I did not noticed any lag. But when I booted the fresh install... dudes, the wallpaper appears slowly from top to bottom, same when I click on the system-menu, the mouse moves slowly when it is over a window, or over the menu, etc.

I installed the intel drivers and I did run update. But still the same problem.

There is anything I can do to solve this before I install another linux distro ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it :

- I deleted the line : `GRUB_CMD_LINE_LINUX="nomodeset"` from `/etc/default/grub` : `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
- then I did a grub update : `sudo update-grub`

note : strange how `nomodeset` was so critical...